# DocumentDB Collection is missing data

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

I'm using my custom DocumentDB Api App (.NET SDK) that reads from a SQL database and pushes this into a collection. This is used in a Logic App.

Logic App Workflow:
SQLConnector -> JSONEncoder -> DocumentDBApiApp

If I check the last step of the DocumentDBApiApp it has 1663 unique ID's that is being written into the collection.

But when I check the collection or query the collection via API Management I only get 505 ID's. Then I triggered the Logic App again and queried the collection again its was 776 ID's and so on.

What am I missing here? I have many logic apps that are build the same way but they are working fine.

Edit: the Sqlconnector is using a stored procedure (database view) to get the data.

Comment: Two questions - what's the indexing policy of the collection, and how are you querying the collection, portal or the SDK? When you query, are you reading all the results by paging through the responses?

Comment: I havent tampered with indexing so i guess its the default. I tried querying via portal, collection and api-call to collection. Same results, all give less than they should and the results are on one page.

Comment: After a few logic app runs the collection almost matches the input now, but a few records is still missing.

Comment: This is now partially solved with a execute with retries pattern, will update here when I have a full solution

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the code containing the query?

One possibility is that you may only be looking at the first page of a set of paginated query results. DocumentDB paginates query results based on several limits (whichever is hit first):

- Response size (1mb)
- RU charge (based on provisioned throughput)
- Response time (5 sec)

When a limit is hit, a page containing whatever DocumentDB found is returned along with a continuation token. A follow-up request using the continuation token will retrieve the next page of results.

Continuation is implemented in the SDK through a query iterable, which allows you to iterate through pages using has executeNextAsync(). You can find a code sample here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/master/samples/code-samples/Queries/Program.cs#L609-L619

Comment: Im using:

Client.UpsertDocumentAsync(currentcollection, document),id) for insert (+ some more logic)

And for querying, im doing it via a API that gets data from docDB. Either by Postman or the portal.

Comment: For REST API Calls via Postman - check the HTTP response headers for a header called `x-ms-continuation`. The value will be a token to pass in as a header for a follow-up HTTP Request to retrieve the next page of results.

Comment: For the portal - click the "next" button to see the next page of results.

Comment: This was a bigger issue than expected. Its solved now and the custom DocumentDB Connector can be found on Git for those interested:
https://github.com/LogicAppComponents/DocumentDbApiApp